# How to disable Wireless Hosted Network's DHCP Server?

Tags: wireless-networking, dhcp

[My Network Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z59CJ.png)

I need to disable the DHCP Server that starts with the wireless hosted network when executing the cmd "netsh wlan start hostednetwork".
Why? Because I have my own DHCP server that I want to configure to listen on the wireless network and on the ethernet network (for desktop computers).

[DHCP PORTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxD4p.png)

More Info:

- I can connect to the internet but it is an other network. (192.168.1.0/24).
- The hosted network is NOT connected to the internet in any way. it is a LAN to share files with wireless devices using a small website on my laptop. (192.168.173.0/24).
- For desktop computers I need to use a cable, setting a static ip does not work because when I enter a gateway, I lose access to the internet... (192.168.3.0/24)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that to enable the hotspot, Windows enables ICS to share the Internet connection.  ICS acts like a router, separating your LAN from the network the hotspot is providing.  Please provide more information on exactly how you've got your hotspot and networking setup.

Comment: There is not ICS in my setup. every network is independent of the others.